# Prove there is $z \in (a,b)$ such that $f(z)=1/k \sum_{n=1}^k f(x_n)$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, proof-writing

Suppose that the function $f:(a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous for $x_1, \ldots ,x_k$ in $(a,b)$. Show there is $z \in (a,b)$ such that $f(z) = \frac{1}{k}\sum_{n=1}^k f(x_n)$

Answer (score 0):

There are $ s\ t\in \{1\ldots k\}\ $ such that

$$ \forall_{n=1}^k\quad f(x_s)\le\ f(x_n)\le\ f(x_t) $$

hence:

$$ f(x_s)\,\ \le\,\ \frac 1k\cdot\sum_{n=1}^k\,f(x_n)\,\le\,\ f(x_t) $$

Thus, there exists
$$ z\ \in\ [\min(x_s\ x_t);\ \max(x_s\ x_t)]\ \subseteq (a;b)\ $$

such that
$$ f(z)\ =\ \frac 1k\cdot\sum_{n=1}^k\,f(x_n) $$

Comment: It's not given that, $f$ is continuous on $(a,b)$, then how can you ensure existence of such $z$.

Comment: If you are just assuming $f$ is continuous at $x_1, \ldots, x_k$, then the statement is false, and there are easy counterexamples: try $f$ that only takes $k$ values.

Comment: I thought that the Q. was a bit sloppy hence I read it as the function was assumed continuous. I don't even know what does *continuous in* $\ x_1\ldots x_k\ $ mean.